# How do I find the roots from this?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Problem: We are give that $2+7i$ is a root of $x^4 - 8x^3 + 73x^2 - 228x + 212=0$

I got stuck on this one: how do I find all the roots?
$\left(i=\sqrt{-1}\right)$

Comment: Are you being asked to determine if the statement is true?

Comment: If $2+7i$ is a root, then so is $2-7i$. Thus you can factor out $x-(2+7i)$ and $x-(2-7i)$, leaving behind a quadratic with two more roots that you can find.

Comment: no eli, i need to find the other roots with the information that one of them is 2+7i

Answer (score 2):

So the roots come in complex conjugate pairs (all the coefficients are real numbers, indeed integers). You will have a factor

$\left(x-(2+7i)\right)\left(x-(2-7i)\right)=\left((x-2)+7i\right)\left((x-2)-7i\right)=(x-2)^2+49=x^2-4x+53$

If you divide your original equation through by this factor, you will get another quadratic factor whose roots you can find in the usual way.

---

Since you know you have a factor, you don't have to do all the division - see if you can spot some short cuts, which will save a lot of time.